# UPDATE command syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Everything here is working except the UPDATE command...  The INSERT works fine but alas, I'm stuck.

```
$queryLastDateArray = "SELECT date FROM schedule ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
$lastDateArray = mysql_query($queryLastDateArray);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($lastDateArray))
                        {
                        $lastDate = $row['date'];
                        }                       
$lastDatePlusOne = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($lastDate)));

$newDatesArray = GetDays($lastDatePlusOne, $_POST[date]);
$i = 0;
while($i < count($newDatesArray))
        {
        if ((date('D', strtotime($newDatesArray[$i]))) == 'Fri')
                {
                $insDate = "INSERT INTO schedule (date) VALUES ('$newDatesArray[$i]')";
                $result = mysql_query($insDate);
                $insEmp = "UPDATE schedule SET schedule.jakes = schedule_default.jakes FROM schedule, schedule_default WHERE schedule.date = '$newDatesArray[$i]' AND schedule_default.ID = '5'";
                $result2 = mysql_query($insEmp);
                }
        $i++;
        }
```

Comment: Never use again `count` in the for/while line. Put in a variable and use the variable itself.

Comment: @Pentium10 - Why not? Is there a reason besides unnecessary micro-optimization?

Comment: For low-latency response time.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing the update like this:

```
 "UPDATE schedule SET schedule.jakes = (SELECT schedule_default.jakes FROM  schedule_default WHERE schedule.date = '$newDatesArray[$i]' AND schedule_default.ID = '5')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple table `UPDATE` syntax is:

```
UPDATE schedule, schedule_default
SET schedule.jakes = schedule_default.jakes
WHERE schedule.date = '$newDatesArray[$i]'
  AND schedule_default.ID = '5'
```